# Why I'm able to use this.state without having to bind or use arrow function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I know that arrow functions inherit the context of the parent, that's why they're so useful in React. However, I have this React component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';


class AlbumList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            albums: [],

        };

        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => {
                 this.setState({ albums: response.data });
            });
    }


    renderAlbums() {
        const { albums } = this.state;
        const array = albums.map(album => (
                <Text>{album.title}</Text>
            ));

        return array;
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderAlbums() }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

And `{ this.renderAlbums() }` is working complete fine without me having to transform `renderAlbums()` into an arrow function. I've been reading other answers on stackoverflow, but they all mention that you NEED arrow function or `bind` in order for `this` to work properly. But in my case it works fine as it is, so why use arrow function inside es6 class?

Comment: I believe it was to do with the lexical `this` of an arrow function.

Comment: @JackBashford but in this example I'm not using arrow function and this.state is pointing at the correct property of the parent class defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using arrow functions then what "this" is is defined by the block that the function is defined in. If you're using "normal" functions then "this" is defined by the place the function gets called from. In this case you're calling it from within the render method so "this" is still an instance of the component. If you tried calling a function like that from something like a buttons onClick then it would fail to find "setState" as "this" would basically be defined by the actual rendered button and not the react class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the **arrow functions** inherit `this` from their parent's scope, but the regular functions inherit `this` from where the function gets called